# FundMe project isn't deploying and getting "No deployment found for: MockV3Aggregator"

Tags: javascript, solidity

When I run this command `yarn hardhat deploy --tags fundme`  I'm getting this MockV3Aggregator error.

`Error: ERROR processing /Users/mohameduzair/blockChain/JSweb3_2/fundMe_hardhat/deploy/01-deploy-fundMe.js:`
`Error: No deployment found for: MockV3Aggregator at Object.get (/Users/mohameduzair/blockChain/JSweb3_2/fundMe_hardhat/node_modules/hardhat-deploy/src/DeploymentsManager.ts:162:17)`

### 01-deploy-fundMe.js deploy script

````
```module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId

    let ethUsdPriceFeedAddress
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        // if (chainId === 31337) {
        const ethUsdAggregator = await deployments.get("MockV3Aggregator")
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = ethUsdAggregator.address
    } else {
        ethUsdPriceFeedAddress = networkConfig[chainId]["ethUsdPriceFeed"]
    }

    const fundMe = await deploy("FundMe", {
        from: deployer,
        args: [ethUsdPriceFeedAddress],
        log: true,
    })
    log(`FundMe deployed at ${fundMe.address}`)
    log(`-------------------------!!!--------------------------`)
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "fundme"] 
```
````

### MockV3Aggregator.sol contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
// pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.8.7;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/tests/MockV3Aggregator.sol";
```

I', new to the Blockchain technologies. I'm following a tutorial on Youtube. I've tried my best. still can not fix this.
What should I do now?
**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending 5 hours, I fixed the bug. It was an extra {curly brace} in my code and a deployment error.

Answer (score 1):

This is Patrick's tutorial, and you need to first deploy the mock.

Please see [here](https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-fund-me-fcc/blob/main/deploy/00-deploy-mocks.js).

Answer (score 1):

If you are following Patrick's tutorial and getting this error then you are probably missing network.name in either of deploy files.
Instead of network.name you have typed only network

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
module.exports.tags = ["all", "fundme"]
```

in 01-deploy-fundMe.js, use

```
module.exports.tags = ["all", "mocks"]
```

and then use command

```
yarn hardhat deploy --tags mocks
```

;)